# Linux doesn't execute scheduled job later than schulded time

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, cron, cron-task

I am beginner with Linux cron job.

**Requirement:**

Record attendance of employee. Every dayat 10 AM a Jar should execute and asks to login to record his/her presence.

**Cron Job**

I have created a cron job and placed at `/etc/cron.d/` and has below line.

```
0 10 * * * /home/user/Documents/attendance.sh
```

If system get started before 10 AM then a login screen UI comes but if user comes late and start system after 10 AM then it doesn't show login screen UI.

So it should execute JAR even though user login after 10 AM.

Also, pleaes let me know if there is another way to achieve this goal.
Please guide.

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 4):

A couple of alternatives occur to me.

**1** If you'd like to have `attendance.sh` run for every user at login, you could add it to the system-wide login shell rc file, probably `/etc/profile`.

**2** If it's available, you could use [`anacron`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron), which is well suited for systems that are not running all the time.  You could schedule `attendance.sh` to run daily at a particular time after login.

These alternatives will behave differently.  **1** will run at each login, so several times a day or only once in several days, depending upon whether the user logs in and out daily, several times daily or stays logged in when they leave work.  **2** will run every day that the user is logged in (assuming that they stay logged in at least as long as the delay you specify).

If your requirements are more exacting, say "run at 10 for all logged in users, otherwise run when a late user logs in".  You could make something work, but doing so would require some extra work.

**Added following questioners comment**

As I alluded to in my discussion of how **1** & **2** differ there can be *problems* with **1** if the user does not just log in at the start of their work day and log out at it's end. It sounds to me as if what you are really after is an application that is tied into the window manager.  I am not experienced with triggering scripts with window manager events, but surely it's possible to do so, e.g. [Run script on screen lock/unlock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock). You may have to do some research depending upon your needs and the sort of systems that you have. One thing to keep in mind is that a solution that works for the user who doesn't log out every day may backfire on those who log out several times a day. Solution **2** may be the best of the easy straightforward solutions for your problem, but you may need something more elaborate to handle edge cases and where (perhaps) employee performance is being monitored.

Comment: I think about the first version, in that case what happens is if user kept his machine on and came next day then he won't be login as start his work. In this case the login screen should popup. So that's why i was thinking to execute everyday at 10 AM

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani I've expanded my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the script run hourly. Script checks the time, if it's 10 or later, it checks if the user logged in today, and if not asks him to login. So you can record the login hour too.

Edit: You can put your script in /etc/cron.hourly